# Managing state with the Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm refactoring some code because the amount of props drilling I was having to do was just unmanageable so I'm taking this as an opportunity to learn about the Context API but I'm just not understanding why state isn't behaving the way I anticipated... Here's my context file:

```
import React,{useState, createContext} from 'react';

export const MileContext = createContext();

export const MileProvider = props => {
    const [totalMiles, setTotalMiles] = useState(0);
    const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState(1);

    return (
        <MileContext.Provider 
        value = {
            [totalMiles, setTotalMiles], 
            [drivers, setDrivers]
            }>
            {props.children}    
        </MileContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

When I change totalMiles from another component and then change drivers from a different component it's apperent that they're sharing a single value... here are the other two components.

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import "./main.css";
import { MileContext } from './MileContext';


const TotalDrivers = () => {
    const [drivers, setDrivers] = useContext(MileContext);
    const onDriverChange = (event) => {
        setDrivers(event.target.value)    
      };

    return(

        <div>
            <p>Total Drivers</p>
            <label>
            <select value={drivers} onChange={onDriverChange}>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            </label>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TotalDrivers;

import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import "./main.css";
import {PRESETS} from "./presets";
import { MileContext } from './MileContext';


const PresetSelector = () => {
    const [totalMiles, setTotalMiles] = useContext(MileContext);
    const onTotalMileChange = (event) => {
        setTotalMiles(event.target.value)    
      };

    return(

            <div>
                <label>
                    <h3>Select a preset for your trip (these are round trips from the warehouse and back)</h3>
                    <select onChange={onTotalMileChange}>
                        <option value="0">Custom Trip</option>
                        {
                        Object.entries(PRESETS).map(([campus, mileage]) => (
                        <option key={campus} value={mileage}>
                            {campus}
                        </option>
                        ))} 
                    </select>
                </label>
                trip total miles = {totalMiles}
            </div>

    )
}

export default PresetSelector;
```

I feel like I'm on the edge of figuring this out but all my googles fall flat. Surely I'm just misunderstanding something or not using the correct syntax. Can you help me understand how to fix this? I have so many other components and state values to add to this app. Oh and I'm wrapping them in app.js like so:

```
  return (
    <MileProvider>

      <Header />
      <form>
      <PresetSelector />
      <TotalDrivers />
      </form>
    </MileProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying  "they are sharing a single value"

Comment: When I use the select in PresetSelector to pick something from the list it displays {totalMiles} but when I change the drivers to 1 or 2 it also changes {totalMiles}. When I pull up state in the react extension I don't see totalMiles and drivers I just see "value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing tuples inside an object without any key which is an invalid syntax.

While passing value to context provider, simply provide the values as an object.

```js
<MileContext.Provider 
        value = {{
            totalMiles, 
            setTotalMiles, 
            drivers, 
            setDrivers
            }}>
            {props.children}    
        </MileContext.Provider>
```

**Usage in TotalDrivers Component:**

```js
const {drivers, setDrivers} = useContext(MileContext);
```

**Usage in PresetSelector component**

```js
const {totalMiles, setTotalMiles} = useContext(MileContext);
```

Comment: You should also consider wrapping the setter functions inside the useCallback, it would handle re render cases